# Java WebView cannot load some of the websites

Tags: java, webview

I am using Webengine to load the website, it is success for loading google & yahoo

but when i used to load "http://www.baidu.org" ,it is not working, but i can use firefox to load successful.

Here is my loading code

```
private void createScene() {  
    PlatformImpl.startup(new Runnable() {  
        @Override
        public void run() {  
            stage = new Stage();  
            stage.setResizable(true);  
            Group root = new Group();  
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);  
            stage.setScene(scene);  
            browser = new WebView();
            webEngine = browser.getEngine();
            webEngine.load("http://www.baidu.org"););
            ObservableList<Node> children = root.getChildren();
            children.add(browser);     
            jfxPanel.setScene(scene);  
        }  
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine to me. What I'm guessing the problem is is that website is a redirect to

```
http://click.linktech.cn/?m=hdys&a=A100171812&l=99999&l_cd1=0&l_cd2=1&tu=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.handuyishe.com
```

Which redirects to *another* website:

```
http://www.handuyishe.com
```

IIRC, the `WebView` control can't handle redirects. You need to load the page, check if there is a redirect, and if there is, load that page.